# Disable SSLv3 using Spring-Boot and embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring-Boot-1.1.8, and I configured ssl with the following properties

```
server.ssl.key-alias=XXX
server.ssl.key-password=XXX
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:XXX
server.ssl.key-store-provider=XXX
server.ssl.key-store-type=XXX.jks
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
```

even though the SSL protocol is TLS, SSLv3 appears to be enabled .
Is it a bug, or I'm missing something?

Just a reminder, using SSLv3, the server may be impacted by the Poodle vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to disable SSLv3, the easiest option is to use Tomcat 7.0.57 which disables it by default. Assuming you're using Maven, all you need to do is set the `tomcat.version` property to 7.0.57 in your pom.

The forthcoming Spring Boot 1.1.10 release uses 7.0.57 by default so, once it's been released, you'll no longer need to set the Tomcat version.